# push old record from database table to bottom of page and newest entry to top of the page

Tags: php

[image: This Image best describes the problem statement]

I want print on the browser, such that 1 remains on the bottom of the page, and the latest entries on top always.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$delay=1; 
$list= array(); 
$arr = array(); 
for($i=0;$i<500;$i++) { 
    $arr[] = $i; 
} 
foreach($arr as $as) { 
    $list[] = $as; 
} 
$sz = count($arr); 
$arss = array_reverse($arr); 
foreach($arss as $ar) {
    ?> 
    <p style="display:none" data-id="<?=$ar?>" id="sort<?=$ar?>" ></p> 
   <?php 
    echo $ar."<br>"; 
    ob_flush(); 
    flush(); 
    sleep($delay); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: <?php
 $delay=1; 
 $list= array(); 
 $arr = array(); 
 for($i=0;$i<500;$i++){
    $arr[] = $i; } 
 foreach($arr as $as){
     $list[] = $as ; 
    }
    $sz = count($arr); 
    $arss = array_reverse($arr); 
    foreach($arss as $ar) {?>
     <p style="display:none" data-id="<?=$ar?>" id="sort<?=$ar?>" ></p>
      <?php echo $ar."<br>"; 
      ob_flush(); 
      flush(); 
      sleep($delay); 
    } 
?>

Comment: Please put the code in your question. You can format it by selecting the code and pressing Ctrl+K.

Comment: I'm afraid that not possible this way, since php can only send html that will be parsed by your browser _in the order it is sent_. You'll need javascript (or some fancy css) to insert new html "in between"